# Nested Sum SQL Query

Tags: sql-server

I have a total to get from SQL server tables that involves sub calculations and am having trouble figuring out how to do the nesting any help would be appriciated.

Tables (NOTE: TRUNCATED TO USEFUL DATA)

PrintJob - ID, DEPT, CopyCount
  has many Imprints (note its a different copy count)
Imprint - ID, JobId, CopyCount
  has many pageDatas
PageData - ImprintID, Index, ImpressionCount

Now for each DEPT I need to get 
SUM of (PrintJob.CopyCount * Sum of its (imprint.CopyCount * Sum of its (imprint's PageData.ImpressionCount)))

So for each imprint need all it's pageData's Impression counts summed and then multipled by the imprint's CopyCount.

This total per imprint can then be summed against each PrintJob to give the number of imprint copies per Printjob, so that can be multiplied by the PrintJob.CopyCount to give the total number of imprints per job.

That can then be summed as each print job per department, to give my final result table, but how can I get that efficiently in one query?

SAMPLE DATA

```
CREATE TABLE PrintJob
(
ID varchar(10),
DEPT varchar(10),
CopyCount int
);

CREATE TABLE Imprint
(
ID varchar(10),
JobId varchar(10),
CopyCount int
);

CREATE TABLE PageData
(
ImprintID varchar(10),
[Index] int,
ImpressionCount int
);

INSERT INTO PrintJob (ID, DEPT, CopyCount)
Values 
('J1','D1',2),
('J2','D1',1),
('J3','D2',5),
('J4','D2',4)
;

INSERT INTO Imprint (ID, JobId, CopyCount)
Values
('I1','J1',1),
('I2','J1',2),
('I3','J2',1),
('I4','J3',2),
('I5','J4',2),
('I6','J4',2)
;

INSERT INTO PageData (ImprintID, [Index], ImpressionCount)
Values 
('I1',1,1),
('I1',2,3),
('I1',3,1),
('I2',1,1),
('I3',1,1),
('I3',2,2),
('I4',1,1),
('I4',2,1),
('I5',1,1),
('I6',1,5)
;
```

Comment: Wite a sample data...

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant tables DDL, some sample data (preferably as DML statements), and the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am right, You mean this:

```
select j.DEPT, sum(j.CopyCount * i.SubCount) TotalCount
from PrintJob j
join (
    select i.JobId, sum(i.CopyCount * p.ICountSum) SubCount
    from Imprint i
        join (
            select ImprintID, SUM(ImpressionCount) ICountSum
            from PageData 
            group by ImprintID) p on p.ImprintID= i.ID
    group by i.JobId) i on i.JobId = j.ID
group by j.DEPT
```